# IAP: normal products + all in one

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

This is my first time with Android IAP, i did make some products in Play Console, and tested them and they all work fine.

The problem started when i wanted to make a new product, so that if a user buys it, he'll have all the other products.

e.g: you can buy 4 or 5 products that are worth X$, and you can buy one product that worth  XX$, which will grant you all what the other small products give you combined.

Is there anyway, to mark the other products as purchased after buying just one?

I hope it was clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this logic in your app, it doesn't exist as built in functionality.

Comment: Thank you, I already did that, if the promo product is purchased, i'd hide all others, else if any normal product is purchased, i'd hide the promo one.